# MySQL occurring responds "Error 9001: Max connect timeout" even root account

Tags: mysql

We face a strange experience. There is the MySQL we are running on GCP.

The metrics (current connection count, CPU, memory, IO, and disk) aren't abnormally high. After 06:25:01, all our connections respond with "Error 9001: Max connect timeout".

I get "too many connections" even when I use the root account. (This is the first time I've seen this happen.) Until we restarted MySQL, everything was fine.

The only thing I'm suspect about is log rotation. We have the audit installed (https://github.com/mcafee-enterprise/mysql-audit). The log rotation was supposed to happen at 06:25:00 every day, but it kept writing until we manually changed it.

Comment: Can you run these commands in a MySQL client: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` and then `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections'`?

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister-site of SO, not here on the programming related SO!

Comment: @BillKarwin max_connections = 5000, max_used_connections = 694

Comment: @Shadow oh, thanks your remind. I hear the https://dba.stackexchange.com/ first time.

Answer (score 1):

The `max_used_connections` status variable is 694, far lower than the limit of `max_connections` at 5000. This indicates that as far as MySQL Server is concerned, you did not come close to running out of connections.

Therefore this must be a limit imposed by the client (and this makes the question appropriate for Stack Overflow, not dba.stackexchange.com).

I've frequently seen cases where the client uses a connection pool of a fixed size, and this runs out of slots long before the MySQL Server's limit is reached. The connection pool size is configured as part of the client application environment, not the database server.

Typically a small connection pool is fine, because the threads of the application should share the pool, acquiring connections as needed, and returning the connection to the pool promptly so other threads can use it.

If threads hold onto their db connections too long, instead of returning them to the pool, then they could occupy all the slots of the connection pool. Then new requests can't acquire connections from the pool when they need them.